# Eclipse: some files are displayed with no colour style

Tags: c, editor, eclipse-cdt

[image]
I have an issue happening in eclipse, where some of the project files (C project) are displayed with no color style. I mean C keywords are colored (like types, or if, else...), but all the variables, functions... are displayed in white. Also, "jump to definition" also does not work for any of them.

Most of the files work well, only some (apparently) random files behave that way.

Please help!

Thank you very much
Nathaniel

======================

## Edit #1

I tried to inverse content of 2 files, one "working" (let's call it W.c) with one which doesn't (F.c).
Copy-pasting the content of W.c in F.c, produces same result, content is displayed with no style.
Doing the opposite (content of F.c in W.c) still displays colors.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. It's certainly not random, or will the identical file or identical file content be displayed once with correct syntax highlighting and once with broken syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Lundin What make you saying this?

Comment: @howlger My user experience of some 5 different Eclipse ports over the years. I don't know which one of them that is the worst IDE ever made, but no other IDE is historically even close to be that bad. The main problem with Eclipse being: it _never works_. Can't write code, can't manage projects, can't compile, can't debug. Other than that, it's ok.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sorry you didn't get along with what you call "Eclipse ports" (probably C/C++ IDEs based on the Eclipse platform and CDT) in the past. I'm using Eclipse on a daily basis for years and I'm happy with it. But how is your comment related to the question asked and in what way it is helpful?

Comment: @howlger It's helpful in such a way that you should forget about getting this IDE working as intended, or you'll soon find yourself in the position of full-time Eclipse technician instead of programmer. The various code formatting templates is just one of many completely broken features.

Comment: @howlger Lundin hates Eclipse. That's all. Actually zillions of users are happy with it. Having worked with VisualStudio in very different versions, Keil µVision, JetBrain's IDEs, and Eclipse for many years, I still prefer Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I dont know how to help you reproduce this

Comment: @Lundin The question is neither about an "Eclipse port" you used in the past, nor about "code formatting templates" (regardless of what you exactly mean by that). Do you also need a full-time technician to turn on your computer?

Comment: @NathanielPerez Your Edit #1 indicates that the two files are opened in different editors. If you right-click on each file, is in the _Open With_ submenu, the selected/marked item the same?

Comment: @howlger Yes they are both marked as C/C++ editor

Comment: @NathanielPerez Please show a screenshot of both editors with the same content side by side. Are both files located in the same folder?

Comment: @howlger they can be in same folder or not. The screen shot I added here is for 2 files in the same folder. Thx

Comment: Could you please show the screenshot not cropped (at least the editor tabs should be contained)? And please also include the code as text. Is this Eclipse 2020-03 without additional plug-ins?

Comment: @howlger i have updated the picture, I hope you can see what you want now

Comment: @howlger any idea?

Comment: Indeed, that looks strange. Your screenshot shows an outdated Eclipse version. Can you reproduce this with Eclipse 2020-03 with CDT 9.11 without additional plug-ins (in two days, on Wednesday, Eclipse 2020-06 with CDT 9.11.1 will be released)?

Comment: I have this kind of issue both with the Java and C++ ports. Simply reloading the file (close it, and re-open it) always works. Also, it mostly happens to me after a source edit outside Eclipse (eg.: git pull). I never really investigated it since there was an easy workaround and it does not happen often (to me, at least). Maybe it is related to your case...